# aeson benchmark space leak (?) on citylots.json

Tags: json, haskell, memory-leaks, aeson

I've been playing around with the [Aeson](https://github.com/bos/aeson) parser's benchmark suite and got some surprising results comparing their strict parser and the lazy one:

- On all datasets that come with the [benchmark](https://github.com/bos/aeson/tree/master/benchmarks), the strict parser always takes more time (this is expected) but never saves any space.
- Running the [`AesonParse`](https://github.com/bos/aeson/blob/master/benchmarks/AesonParse.hs) benchmark on [`citylots.json`](https://github.com/zeMirco/sf-city-lots-json) takes dramatically more time and space than other datasets of comparable size.

To get the benchmark running:

```
cd aeson; cabal install
cd benchmark; make
./AesonParse_p [blksz] [runs] [path-to-json] +RTS -p -hc
```

Here are some profiles I got with `+RTS` turned on:

From the profiles the leak traced back to `jstring_` in `Data.Aeson.Parser.Internal` Anyone knows what's going on?

```
    Sun Nov 15 13:56 2015 Time and Allocation Profiling Report  (Final)

       AesonParse_p +RTS -p -hc -RTS 105532 700 json-data/jp100.json

    total time  =        3.42 secs   (3417 ticks @ 1000 us, 1 processor)
    total alloc = 4,191,614,072 bytes  (excludes profiling overheads)

COST CENTRE          MODULE                     %time %alloc

jstringbang_         Data.Aeson.Parser.Internal  96.4   93.1
arrayValues          Data.Aeson.Parser.Internal   1.7    1.9
object_'             Data.Aeson.Parser.Internal   1.1    1.9
main.\.\.loop.refill Main                         0.7    3.2


                                                                         individual     inherited
COST CENTRE               MODULE                       no.     entries  %time %alloc   %time %alloc

MAIN                      MAIN                         116           0    0.0    0.0   100.0  100.0
 main                     Main                         233           0    0.0    0.0   100.0  100.0
  main.blkSize            Main                         242           1    0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
  main.count              Main                         239           1    0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
  main.\                  Main                         234           1    0.0    0.0   100.0  100.0
   main.\.\               Main                         235           1    0.0    0.0   100.0  100.0
    main.\.\.rate         Main                         252           1    0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
    main.\.\.loop         Main                         238         701    0.1    0.0   100.0  100.0
     object_'             Data.Aeson.Parser.Internal   245           0    1.1    1.9    99.2   96.8
      jstring_        Data.Aeson.Parser.Internal   247           0   96.4   93.1    98.1   94.9
       array_'            Data.Aeson.Parser.Internal   249           0    0.0    0.0     1.7    1.9
        arrayValues       Data.Aeson.Parser.Internal   251           0    1.7    1.9     1.7    1.9
     main.\.\.loop.refill Main                         241           1    0.7    3.2     0.7    3.2
 CAF                      GHC.IO.FD                    217           0    0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
 CAF                      GHC.IO.Encoding.Iconv        215           0    0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
 CAF                      Text.Read.Lex                209           0    0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
 CAF                      GHC.IO.Handle.FD             202           0    0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
 CAF                      GHC.Conc.Signal              198           0    0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
 CAF                      GHC.IO.Handle.Text           191           0    0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
 CAF                      GHC.IO.Encoding              188           0    0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
 CAF                      Data.Time.Clock.UTC          129           0    0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
 CAF                      Data.Aeson.Parser.Internal   124           0    0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
  array_'                 Data.Aeson.Parser.Internal   248           1    0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
   arrayValues            Data.Aeson.Parser.Internal   250           1    0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
  jstringbang_            Data.Aeson.Parser.Internal   246           1    0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
  object_'                Data.Aeson.Parser.Internal   244           1    0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
 CAF                      Main                         123           0    0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
  main                    Main                         232           1    0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
   main.blkSize           Main                         243           0    0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
   main.count             Main                         240           0    0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
   main.\                 Main                         236           0    0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
    main.\.\              Main                         237           0    0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
```

[image]

Comment: What are the other json datasets of comparable size?

Comment: I truncated citylots to ~ 20MB and compared with files from http://jsonstudio.com/resources/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can tell this is should be expected.

The file citylots.json is a 167 MB file consisting of a single Object. The AesonParse program is building the entire object in memory, and that explains the memory ramp in the profile.

By contrast, the files companies.json and enron.json at http://jsonstudio.com/resources/  are "line-oriented" JSON files - each line is a JSON object and there are no commas between the objects. When you run AesonParse on either of these files it is only reading the first line.